# Iterate Nested JSON Object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

```
{
  "main": [
    {
      "Processing": [
        {
          "Renovation": [
            {
              "Registration": [
                {
                  "Data": "trtl1"
                },
                {
                  "Purpose": [
                    {
                      "Address": "info"
                    },
                    {
                      "Information": "pinfo"
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "Info": "app.loaninfo"
                },
                {
                  "7.MCC": [
                    {
                      "Info": "info"
                    },
                    {
                      "MHC": "mhc"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "Borrow": [
            {
              "Personal": "bor"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Audit": [
        {
          "Lookup": [
            {
              "HMDA": "app"
            },
            {
              "Pro": "app1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

### }

This is my JSON and I would need to iterate in AngularJS/Javascript to get the value.This is not static data but dynamic set of data, I need to iterate and get value like "Processing","Renovation","Registration",
"Data","Purpose","Address" from the JSON and store it in js object build parent/child relation to display as menu and submenu in UI screen

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: So parse the JSON and then use a loop (or nested loops). Where are you stuck?

Comment: I tried but I don't how to read "Processing" with this code angular.forEach(data.main, function(value,index) {  
          console.log('****'+ value);
         });

Comment: What's the expected result of all this?

Comment: expected result is I need to loop the json and retrieve the value

Comment: var kyArr = [];
       for(var i=0;i<data.main.length;i++){
        var obj = data.main[i];
        for ( var key in obj) {
         kyArr.push(key);
        }
       }